# Compiling Qt using MinGW on Win64 - which MinGW?

Tags: windows, qt, mingw

Based on [these instructions](https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings/blob/master/README.txt) I'm trying to install/compile Qt 4.8.6 on Windows 7x64 using MinGW 4.8.2. Per those instructions I went to get MinGW from [this site](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php), which leads me to [win-builds.org](http://win-builds.org/download.html).

The result is that I have a directory filled with various mingw executables: `x86_64-w64-mingw32-c++.exe`, `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-4.8.2.exe`, `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe`, `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8.2.exe`, `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ar-4.8.2.exe`, `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-nm-4.8.2.exe`, `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ranlib-4.8.2.exe`, `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe`.

When I go to install Qt, it asks where MinGW is:
[image: screenshot of MinGW installer step.]

But when I supply the path to all those executables, it says that it cannot find `g++`:
[image: There is a problem with your MinGW installation: g++ not found in C:\Program Files\Utilities\winbuilds\bin\bin Do you still want to continue? (Your installation may not work)]

Do I need to alias one of those executables to a different name for Qt to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I only noticed when posting the above screenshot, the Qt installer is adding an extra `\bin` to the path. Giving it the location of the parent folder of the executables worked, in my case just:
`C:\Program Files\Utilities\winbuild`